# Is it safe to whitelist my public ip to a server, even I am behind CGNAT?

Tags: databases, isp, vps

I have a few VPS and Databases in GCP, I can access them by whitelisting my IP, but just few months ago my ISP rollout their CGNAT and I was affected. As far as I know CGNAT, allow multiple subscriber to have a single public IP.

Is still safe to whitelist my IP or I need another means or extra layer of protection?

Comment: What services on the VPS are exposed?

Comment: @multithr3at3d ssh to manage and deploy code

Answer (score 1):

If whitelisting your public IP address is the only form auf authentication then it is not safe because with NAT (including CGNAT) this IP address might be shared at the same time with other clients. If instead whitelisting the public IP address is only additional defense and proper authentication is still done, then IP based restrictions are still useful: even if the same IP address is shared with **some others** which might thus pass this first line of defense it is still much better than have no whitelisting at all which would mean that **all others** could pass this line of defense.